# Uploading multiple files in Django through one form field

Tags: python, django, forms, upload

Is there any custom widget (or a special magic way) to upload multiple files (or a whole folder!) through one form field?
I have tried [this multifile widget](http://scompt.com/blog/archives/2007/11/03/multiple-file-uploads-in-django) but it uses many simple FileFileds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://github.com/tstone/django-uploadify is a reusable Django app that integrates http://uploadify.com.

From Uploadify's website:

> Uploadify is a jQuery plugin that integrates a fully-customizable multiple file upload utility on your website.  It uses a mixture of Javascript, ActionScript, and any server-side language to dynamically create an instance over any DOM element on a page.

Answer (score 11):

HTML 5 now allows for multiple file uploads in a single form control.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.file.html#input.file.attrs.multiple

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't do that - HTML file inputs don't allow it.

Answer (score 3):

As Daniel said, File Input fields cannot support more than one file. However, there are ways around this using Things like [SWFUpload](http://swfupload.org/). How you might integrate that workflow into a Django application, I'm not too sure.

Comment: SWFupload is perfect for multiple file uploads in django and easy to implement (its a classic upload). The only gotcha is if you need authentication; You have to be careful to use the swfupload.cookies plugin if you need authentication. also, add this decorator to your view to allow cookie login  : http://github.com/revolunet/django-skeleton/blob/master/core/decorators.py#L19