# Upload entire directory in django

Tags: django, file-upload

I'm trying to make a web interface in django for clients to upload the entire contents of a folder to my website.  This will be useful for when I'm building sites for clients which have a lot of images (artists/event planners/etc). Even though getting a zip file would be easier, being able to just grab a directory would be nicer for my...erm...less technically inclined clients.  So, is there anyway I can create a django form which will accept and upload all files within a directory?

I can find plenty examples on how to do single files and they seem straight forward enough but I'd really prefer something that will take a directory and grab everything within that directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably all decent browsers prevent arbitrary filesystem access. You *can* however use javascript to select all files in a directory and iterate over them creating an upload field in your multipart form for each one of them.

There are some freebies out there, e.g. http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your are looking for https://github.com/tstone/django-uploadify. If you need some more details, also have a look here: [Uploading multiple files in Django through one form field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1706880/uploading-multiple-files-in-django-through-one-form-field).

And just saw, that [blueimp](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/) comes with builtin Django Backend as well

However, be aware, that you need "modern" browsers for this to work :-), it will probably not be compatible down to IE 6 or 7