# Python / Django - Upload Folder

Tags: javascript, python, django, html, file-upload

I'm building a medical system that doctors will upload their patient data (Exam pictures) from a directory.

Searching and searching I figured out that HTML5 has a tag named "directory", like this example:

http://www.w3bees.com/2013/03/directory-upload-using-html-5-and-php.html

So far, seems like I solved my front-end problem! And now? How to handle multiple files upload on my back-end using Python and this HTML5 tag??

PS: The example above is only one input file, not multiple. I'm trying to achieve the same.

Comment: Not sure I'd like my private medical details loaded into a browser using html5 over the net

Comment: Yeah, that's another point, it depends on if the doctor browser is up to date or not to be safe and so on... Tons of variables.. Not easy task here bro! hahaha

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upload entire directory in django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12101699/upload-entire-directory-in-django)

Comment: @HansThen, not duplicated, I'm asking about HTML5 new tag and how to handle it on my back-end...

Comment: You are right. I retracted the vote.