# django - Upload a folder under media

Tags: django

I'm trying to upload an entire folder (of images) inside the media_root in django.

I want something like `im = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/", blank=True, null=True)` but I do not want to upload many images one by one. 
How can I do that? There is a simple way to use FileField or ImageField that upload directly the folder instead of a file/image?

Answer (score 0):

I've done some digging around and it doesn't seem possible. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12101699/upload-entire-directory-in-django). You can use some JS to select all the files in the directory you want to upload and then create an upload field for each of the files.