# Can we upload a tree structure in one go to django server? Like we do using git?

Tags: django, git

Can we upload a tree structure in one go to the Django server?
Eg:- A whole directory, as we do by using git?

We can use multiple file upload in Django but that doesn't solve the issue for hierarchical tree structure upload.
I want the hierarchical structure to be intact while uploading the folder in Django.

Comment: are you talking about file upload in a particular path? like /media/user_1/img1.png and /media/user_2/img1.png?

Comment: The question is unclear ... if you mean representing a tree structure in a Django-controlled DB, there are multiple solutions in https://djangopackages.org/ (search for Tree). Have not used any so can't suggest further.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upload entire directory in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12101699/upload-entire-directory-in-django)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdjango%5D+upload+directories

Comment: @NalinDobhal please check the updated question.

Comment: @nigel222 please check the updated question.

Comment: @phd no actually that particular question contains only two answers both of which are inappropriate or doesn't work.

Comment: There are 2 ways. Either you teach your users to create an archive (like zip) and upload it or use multiple upload. The duplicate question suggests tools to simplify multiple upload.