# Using Python-django or html how to upload multiple files without using any packages?

Tags: python

I want to upload multiple files.I don't want to use jquery plugin or python packages.Is it possible to upload multiple files using html/JavaScript without using  packages. 
Please share your valuable thoughts regarding this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [sources](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_multiple.asp), in HTML5 you can do like,

`<input type="file" name="multiple_file_field" multiple>`

Comment: Adding to it, "multiple" attribute is a part of HTML5, so declare the DOCTYPE accordingly.

Comment: I have tried uploading file using it before " <input type="file" name="multiple_file_field" multiple>" but i was only  able to upload only 1 file .The previous file gets replaced with the current file.    Now am looking forward to implement this using django forms i was able to upload 1 file using django forms Is there any way to implement this using django forms using packages.

Comment: In this way you can multi select the files in a same directory. If you want to upload files from different directories you need to define *multiple number* of input file tags. Does that make sense?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1706880/uploading-multiple-files-in-django-through-one-form-field Check there. But uploadify needs jQuery. Either you can define any number of `FileField` in your form or can specify `attr` of a single `FileField` to `multiple`.

Comment: Yes it does make sense.But as per my requirement i want only one Upload file button and the files uploaded should be shown below beneath it..

Comment: I want to upload multiple file using django forms since i have done lots of validation using django forms.It would be useful  if anyone has uploaded multiple files using -django-multiuploader package and please let me know how to implement it.