# How to process and discard multiple uploaded files in Django

Tags: python, django, upload, django-forms, request

[Updated question]

I need to analyze multiple files sent by the users and render an output page with this analysis. These files should not be kept in a database, but parsed, analyzed and discarded. I can do this with one single file, with the code below, using `django.core.files.uploadedfile.InMemoryUploadedFile`.

I tried to implement DropzoneJS, but it didn't work. For each file uploaded, the analysis output page is rendered.

How could I upload multiple files in Django to process, render a result page and discard them?

#### views.py

```
def load_files(request):
    return render(request, 'forms.html', {})

def analysis(request):
    my_data = []
    for name, uploaded_file in request.FILES.items():
        # do something with uploaded_file and output 'data'
        my_data.append(data)
    return render(request, 'analysis.html', {'my_data': my_data})
```

#### forms.html

```
<form action="{% url 'analysis' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary"/>
</form>
```

PS: In dropzone implementation, the `form` in forms.html was:

```
<form action="{% url 'analysis' %}" method="post" class="dropzone" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary"/>
</form>
```

Comment: What exact count of files did you notice in: `request.FILES`

Comment: Thats why you will get only one file to extract data. So your solution is to check how to select multiple files and send for `POST/PUT` request.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1706880/uploading-multiple-files-in-django-through-one-form-field